# Unwrap optional properties automatically in enum

Tags: swift, enums

Currently I'm using enum to define APIs. One of my api is posting a note, with an image or not.

```
enum StoreAPI {
    ...
    case newNote(String, Data?) /* note_description, note_image */
}
```

As I know to handle this case, there are two ways:

```
// Option 1
switch api {
...
case let newNote(description, imageData):
   if let imageData = imageData {
       // Post with image
   }
   else {
      // Post without image
   }
...
}

// Option 2
switch api {
    ...
    case let newNote(description, nil):
       // Post without image
    case let newNote(description, imageData):
       let imageData = imageData!
    ...
}
```

I'm wondering if is there any other way to unwrap optional value automatically, or handle it better, or more clearly.

Comment: Compare [Swift pattern matching with enum and Optional tuple associated values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32859646/2976878) – you can use the optional pattern.

Comment: Oh, I can't find any information about .Some(foo) in Swift 3.1. Is it a new custom enumeration? It could be the better way to unwrap optional value automatically

Comment: `.some(Wrapped)` (previously `.Some(Wrapped)`) is one of the cases of [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional) – it's an `enum` itself :) But as Martin shows in his answer, there's a syntactic sugar form of it, by simply adding a `?` to the end of the bound value's identifier – in your case, `case let .newNote(description, imageData?):`.

Comment: Omg! I should take a closer look into `Optional`. My bad eyes.. Thank you so much @Hamish!!

Comment: Why not two cases `newNote` and `newNoteWithImage`?

Comment: @vadian if splitting in 2 cases, we've to check `imageData` is `nil` or not to use the correct case. It somehow equivalent to Option1, but even worse since you have to check it again if create new value. Why not let the `switch-case` handle it :)

Comment: Not really: At the moment to check for `nil` on the *sender* side you are unwrapping the optional simultaneously. That's only one step. Your `case let` and later the unwrapping are two steps.

Comment: @vadian: Not really understand "check fo nil on the sender side you are unwrapping the optional simultaneously", while I just need to put `let api = .newNote(foo, bar)`, which `bar: Data? = parseImage(...)`. Of course I could have to check for `nil` in `parseImage(...)` but in my StoreAPI, have less case to handle is better, since it follows `Moya.framework`

Comment: With *sender* I mean the code to create the case for example `if let image = imageData { api = .newNoteWithImage(description, image) } else { api = .newNote(description)  }`. Now the image data is already unwrapped.

Comment: I see. Follow to your idea, if I create 3 instances in other classes, I have to check it again and again. Or I have to create another function to wrap `if..else..`. It's quite like a copy paste which I don't think it's good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141886/discussion-between-nahung89-and-vadian).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use optional enum's `.some` binding:

```
enum StoreAPI {
    case newNote(String, Data?)
}

// sample data
let api = StoreAPI.newNote("title", "data".data(using: .utf8))

switch api {

case let .newNote(title, .some(data)):
    print("title: \(title), data: \(data)")

default:
    break

}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3.1

Thank @Hamish for the suggestion. I would like to post the answer here to others who might have this issue.

```
switch api {
...
case let .newNote(description, .none):
   // image data is nil, post without it.
case let .newNote(description, .some(imageData)):
   // imageData is available and unwrapped automatically to use.
...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I'm having the down vote. This code is tested and work great as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way in swift would be to use the optional `?` operator, rather than `Optional.some` which others have suggested. (However, this is just syntactic sugar - they are the same thing) An example can be seen below:

```
switch api {

case let .newNote(title, data?):
    break // Do stuff with title & data

default:
    break

}
```

Comment: Yea! As I check here it's could be another option to deal with unwrap optional automatically. `case let .newNote(title, nil): /* Do stuff with title only */ break; case let .newNote(title, data?): /* Do stuff with title & data */ ...`

Comment: @nahung89 :+1: yes you're right, `nil` is just syntactic sugar for `Optional.none`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code to be very explicit on your intent, you could use a where clause:

```
switch api 
{
  case let .newNote(description, imageData) where imageData == nil:

       // Post without image

  case let .newNote(description, imageData?):

       // Post with image
  default : break
}
```

Comment: It's the same with Option 2, which I posted above. From my point, we have to unwrap `imageData` ourself, which can handle better with `.some(foo)` or `.none` (you can see my answer below) :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were simply  trying to find a clearer way to express it, (and i forgot the ? on the second case, my bad).